# If $F(x,y)=f(xy)$ then is it true that $xF_x(x,y)=yF_y(x,y)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Here, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $F_x$ etc. denote partial derivatives. It is clearly true for analyticfunctions, but I don't see a general argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the chain rule for both derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary proof using Calc I. Assuming $f$ is differentiable we have
$$
F_x(x,0)=\lin_{h_1\to 0}\frac{F(x+h_1,0)-F(x,0)}{h_1}=\lim_{h_1\\to 0}{f(0)-f(0)}{h_1}=0,
$$
and for $y \ne 0$

\begin{eqnarray}
F_x(x,y)
&=&\lim_{h_1\to 0}\frac{F(x+h_1,y)-F(x,y)}{h_1}\cr
&=&y\lim_{h_1\to 0}\frac{f(xy+h_1y)-f(xy)}{h_1y}\cr
&=&y\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(yx+t)-f(xy)}{t}\cr
&=&yf'(xy).
\end{eqnarray}
Hence

$$\tag{1}
F_x(x,y)=yf'(xy) \quad \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
Since $F(y,x)=f(yx)=f(xy)=F(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, it followS From (1) that

$$\tag{2}
F_y(x,y)=xf'(xy) \quad \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$

Thus, combining (1) and (2), we have

$$
xF_(x,y)=xyf'(xy)=yxf'(xy)=yF_y(x,y) \quad \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2.
$$